# ASP .NET MVC 2. InsertionMode.Replace in AjaxOptions dosent work right

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am trying to replace `<div>` content after a form submit. Here is the code (it is a partial view):

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Authenticate", "User", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", UpdateTargetId = "authPanel", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{%>
    <label>Username</label><%= Html.ValidatedTextBoxFor(username => Model.UserAuthienficateDto.Username, false) %>
    <label>Password</label><%= Html.ValidatedTextBoxFor(password => Model.UserAuthienficateDto.Password, false) %>
    <input name="Input" type="submit" class="button" value="Authenticate" />
<%}%>
<div id="authPanel">
<ul>
    <% if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {%>
        <li class="nonregister">Logged in as <%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%></li>
        <li class="register"><%= Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "User")%></li>
    <%
        }%>
    <% else
    {%>
        <li class="nonregister">Not a member &nbsp;?</li>
        <li id="userRegisterDialogOpener" class="register">Sign up now!</li>
    <%}%>
</ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that after form submit I get whole partial view re-rendered. Also all the results are being rendered above the old ones (they have some offset though). Why InsertionMode.Replace is not working properly? Mant thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by separating form and authPanel to different partial views.